# Applying variables in a function from private function - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I am using Node.js with bluebird and am trying to use defaultMySQLOutput as a model for output as such:

```
function defaultMySQLOutput(err, result){
    return err ? reject(err) : resolve(result);
}

function something(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        mysql.query(q, defaultMySQLOutput);
    });
}
```

but this does not work. The error says "resolve is undefined", but when I do

```
mysql.query(q, function(err, results){
    resolve(results);
});
```

it works.

I've also tried,

```
defaultMySQLOutput.call(this, err, results)
```

and

```
(new defaultMySQLOutput)
```

but unable to make it happen. Is there a way to make this work? Any reference would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it work with _mysql.query_ because you call it inside `new Promise(function(resolve, reject){`

Comment: Right, so I'm trying to call defaultMySQLOutput from within that function. Any idea?

Comment: you can try something like `defaultMySQLOutput(resolve, reject,err, result)` and use like `mysql.query(q, defaultMySQLOutput.bind(this,resolve,reject));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the power of closures to create a new function that will have access to `resolve` and `reject` correctly:

```
function defaultMySQLOutput(resolve, reject) {
    return function (err, result) {
        return err ? reject(err) : resolve(result);
    }
}

function something(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        mysql.query(q, defaultMySQLOutput(resolve, reject));
    });
}
```

Comment: Great. I didn't think about that, and thanks! I can accept yours as an answer in 8 minutes...